# How to print a new line if a pattern from a column matches in 2 lines?

Tags: text-processing

I have the following file:

```
transcr_15824 -
YML042W -
transcr_18545 -
YCR105W +
transcr_16934 +
YDR032C +
transcr_15237 +
YDL008W -
```

I do need something that looks like this:

```
transcr_15824 -
YML042W -
Match
transcr_18545 -
YCR105W +
Not
transcr_16934 +
YDR032C +
Match
transcr_15237 +
YDL008W -
Not
```

Edit: Basically I need to compare the second column for each two lines. If second column for the first line matches with the second column for the second line, it's a match. If second column for the first line doesn't match with the second column for the second line, it's not a match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
$ awk '{print} !(NR%2){if($2 == last) print "Match"; else print "Not"} {last = $2}' file
transcr_15824 -
YML042W -
Match
transcr_18545 -
YCR105W +
Not
transcr_16934 +
YDR032C +
Match
transcr_15237 +
YDL008W -
Not
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -pae '($_ .= <>) .= qw/NO MATCH/[0+/\n.*\s\Q$F[1]\E$/] . $/'  input
```

Operate perl in auto split mode. 2nd field is $F[1] is compared in the next line, <>, and depending on itz presence match or no match is appended to the current line $_.